# Should entity objects be exposed by the repository?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, repository, repository-pattern

I have an repository which implements interface `IRepository`.  The repository performs queries on the Entity Framework (on behalf of) the application and directly returns the entity object produced.

The whole point in implementing `IRepository` is so that it can be switched out for different repositories in the future.  However returning the exact entity objects as returned by the Entity Framework will break this. Is this acceptable?

Therefore should the repository be converting all Entity Framework objects into business objects prior to exposing them to the application?  Should such objects implement an interface or have a common base type?

Comment: What 'different repositories' would you want to support.  Do you mean switching from EF to NHibernate?  If that is the case, you will probably incur a lot more changes than the IRepository interface.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of anything in particular but I want my application to be robust.  What other changes are you thinking?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The repository interface should deal only with **business/domain entities**, that is the repository sends and receives only objects known by the app, objects that aren't related to the underlying peristence access implementation.

EF or Nhibernate entities are modelling the persistence data **NOT** the domain ones. So IRepository should not return an object which is an implementation detail of the ORM, but an object that can be used directly by the app (either a domain entity or a simplified view model, depending on the operation).

In the repository implementation, you deal with ORM entities which will be mapped to the corresponding app entities (usually with a mapper such as AutoMapper). Long story short, when designing IRepository forget all about its implementation. That's why is better to design the interface before deciding if/what ORM will be used.

Basically, the repository is the gateway between the app domain context and the persitence context and the app SHOULD NOT be coupled to the implementation details of the repository.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at using one of the POCO templates for generating your entities. That way your entities have no special dependencies on Entity Framework, and can be passed freely between layers. It saves a whole lot of effort compared to maintaining a completely separate domain model and mapping between the two (unless your domain model would be significantly different from your entity model, in which case it would make more sense).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using POCO entities, you can assume that any provider will do a similar job. Also, remember that you are returning entities, which have their properties mapped to database. So you can assume that unless entities have different property names for each provider(I can not find a logical explanation of having different names), you can return them from repository to business directly.